# Trouble writing é in emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, keyboard

I'm using emacs(version below) on Windows7(x64). I have trouble writing a é in emacs.

I would like to hit '´' and 'e' to get the char 'è'.

I have used emacs for >20years and I do not remember it has been a trouble before. It has worked before, I'm almost sure of... There is no problem displaying the 'é', and I can cut-and-paste from other programs/buffers. The problem is to type it.

Any solution would be much appreciated.
BR/Tomas

(GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2012-02-04 on MARVIN)

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

Typing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> will display an input table for all Latin-1 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .emacs file if you want to type "'" "e" to get "é"

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after activate-input-method activate)
(activate-input-method "latin-9-prefix"))
```

If you want to just activate it for one session, do

```
M-x set-input-method
```

and enter

```
latin-9-prefix
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a keyboard setting with dead keys, which makes `'` + `e` = `é`, like the us-international keyboard map (if I remember correctly?) you might want to put `(require 'iso-transl)` somewhere in your emacs init file.

I don't use Windows, but I don't see any warning about it in the `iso-transl` elisp file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of the most common special characters to use and also type fluently.

ä - M-d

Ä - M-D

ë - M-k

Ë - M-K

ï - M-o

Ï - M-O

ö - M-v

Ö - M-V

ü - M-| (*argh*, I've to use shift for the non-capitals and vice versa)

Ü - M-\ (dito.)

ß - M-_ (dito.)

é - M-i

É - M-I

è - M-h

È - M-H

à = M-`

À = M-@

Courtesy - [LINK](http://fsinfo.noone.org/~abe/typing-8bit.html)

Comment: Obviously you need to prefix these with `C-q` in Emacs.